# .Net MAUI Webview file upload not working

Tags: android, ios, maui

I'm very new in .Net MAUI. Working on a webview that have file upload option. I added read/write permissions to AndroidManifest.xml. Permission popup shows and it granted. But, no file uploader shows up.

Added in AndroidManifest.xml
`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" /> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />`

Permission popup granted. But, nothing show up.

I found some xamarin code via google search, but can't able to implement. Can anyone please give a .Net MAUI working code for webview file uploder.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After lots of back and forth trying, able to solve the issue. Below is my complete solution. Hope it will help other who needs it in future.

Thank you `Liyun Zhang - MSFT` for your code, it will not solve my purpose.

Step 1. Modify the MainActivity under the Platfrom/Android folder.

```
public class MainActivity : MauiAppCompatActivity
{
    public static IValueCallback mUploadCallbackAboveL;     
    public static Android.Net.Uri imageUri;     
    public static MainActivity Instance;     
    public static int PHOTO_REQUEST = 10023;

     protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)     {                   
        base.OnCreate(bundle);         
        HandleIntent(Intent);         
        Instance = this;          

        if (ContextCompat.CheckSelfPermission(this, Manifest.Permission.Camera) != (int)Permission.Granted){              

        }     
    }

    protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, Result resultCode, Android.Content.Intent intent) 
    {
        if (resultCode == Result.Ok){             
            if (intent != null && intent.Data !=null) // Camera photo   {                 
                if (null == mUploadCallbackAboveL) return;                
                Android.Net.Uri result = intent == null || resultCode != Result.Ok ? null : intent.Data;                    
                //mUploadMessage.OnReceiveValue(result);                    
                mUploadCallbackAboveL.OnReceiveValue(new Android.Net.Uri[] { result });                     
                mUploadCallbackAboveL = null;             
            }             
            else if (requestCode == PHOTO_REQUEST){                 
                if (mUploadCallbackAboveL != null){                         
                    onActivityResultAboveL(requestCode, resultCode, intent);                 
                }                               
            }         
        }         
        else {             
            if (resultCode != Result.Ok){                 
                mUploadCallbackAboveL.OnReceiveValue(null);                 
                mUploadCallbackAboveL = null;                 
                return;             
            }         
        }
    }

    private void onActivityResultAboveL(int requestCode, Result resultCode, Android.Content.Intent data){
    
        if (requestCode != PHOTO_REQUEST || mUploadCallbackAboveL == null){
            return;
        }

        Android.Net.Uri[] results = null;         
        if (resultCode == Result.Ok){             
            results = new Android.Net.Uri[] { imageUri };             
            results[0] = MainActivity.imageUri;         
        }         

        mUploadCallbackAboveL.OnReceiveValue(results);         
        mUploadCallbackAboveL = null;
    }

}
```

Step 2. Implement a custom WebChromeClient under the Platfrom/Android folder.

```
internal class MyWebChromeClient : WebChromeClient{

    private MainActivity activity = null;

    public MyWebChromeClient(MainActivity context){             
        this.activity = context;         
    }

    public override void OnPermissionRequest(PermissionRequest request){
        foreach (var resource in request.GetResources()) {                 
            if (resource.Equals(PermissionRequest.ResourceVideoCapture, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))                        
            {   
                // Get the status of the .NET MAUI app's access to the camera                     
                PermissionStatus status = Permissions.CheckStatusAsync<Permissions.Camera>().Result;                                
                
                // Deny the web page's request if the app's access to the camera is not "Granted"                     
                if (status != PermissionStatus.Granted)                         
                    request.Deny();                     
                else                         
                    request.Grant(request.GetResources());
                      
                return;                 
            }             
        }            
             
        base.OnPermissionRequest(request);
    }

    public override bool OnShowFileChooser(WebView webView, IValueCallback filePathCallback, FileChooserParams fileChooserParams){
        MainActivity.mUploadCallbackAboveL = filePathCallback;

        //PickPhoto;              
        var imageStorageDir = FileSystem.Current.CacheDirectory;

        // Create picked image file path and name, add ticks to make it unique               
        var file = new Java.IO.File(imageStorageDir + Java.IO.File.Separator + "IMG_" + DateTime.Now.Ticks + ".jpg");

        //MainActivity.imageUri = Uri.FromFile(file);             
        MainActivity.imageUri = FileProvider.GetUriForFile(activity, activity.PackageName + ".fileprovider", file);

        //Create camera capture image intent and add it to the chooser               
        var captureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ActionImageCapture);                      
        captureIntent.PutExtra(MediaStore.ExtraOutput, MainActivity.imageUri);

        var i = new Intent(Intent.ActionGetContent);             
        i.AddCategory(Intent.CategoryOpenable);             
        i.SetType("image/*");

        var chooserIntent = Intent.CreateChooser(i, "Choose Image");                    
        chooserIntent.PutExtra(Intent.ExtraInitialIntents, new Intent[] { captureIntent });

        MainActivity.Instance.StartActivityForResult(chooserIntent, MainActivity.PHOTO_REQUEST);

        return true;
    }
}
```

Step 3. Modify the AndroidManifest.xml under the Platfrom/Android folder.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />   
<!--<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" android:maxSdkVersion="32" />   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" android:maxSdkVersion="32" />-->   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>   
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />   
   
<!-- Required only if your app needs to access images or photos that other apps created -->   
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES" />   

<!-- Required only if your app needs to access videos that other apps created -->   
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_VIDEO" />   

<!-- Required only if your app needs to access audio files that other apps created -->   
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_AUDIO" />      
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera"/>  

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="23" android:targetSdkVersion="33" />    
<queries>     
    <intent>       
        <action android:name="android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE" />     
    </intent>  
</queries>
```

Step 4. MainPage.Xaml looks like below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"                  
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"              
    x:Class="UPloadFile.MainPage"              
    Title="Uplodad file webview">              

    <WebView Loaded="WebView_Loaded"              
        x:Name="myWebView" 
        Source="Source link">         
    </WebView>  
</ContentPage>
```

Step 5. MainPage.Xaml.cs looks like below.
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
public Dashboard(){
InitializeComponent();
}

```
    protected override void OnHandlerChanged(){
        base.OnHandlerChanged();

        #if ANDROID
            var webview = myWebView.Handler.PlatformView as Android.Webkit.WebView;         
            webview.SetWebChromeClient(new STC_Delivery_App.Platforms.Android.MyWebChromeClient(MainActivity.Instance));          
            if (webview is not null){             
                webview.Settings.MediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture = false;              
                webview.Settings.SetGeolocationEnabled(true);             
                webview.Settings.JavaScriptEnabled = true;         
            }
        #endif
    }

    private async void WebView_Loaded(object sender, EventArgs e){
        
        PermissionStatus status = await Permissions.CheckStatusAsync<Permissions.Camera>();

        if (status != PermissionStatus.Granted){             
            if (Permissions.ShouldShowRationale<Permissions.Camera>()) { }              
            await Permissions.RequestAsync<Permissions.Camera>();         
        }

        status = await Permissions.CheckStatusAsync<Permissions.StorageRead>();
        
        if (status != PermissionStatus.Granted){             
            if (Permissions.ShouldShowRationale<Permissions.StorageRead>()) { }              
            await Permissions.RequestAsync<Permissions.StorageRead>();         
        }

        status = await Permissions.CheckStatusAsync<Permissions.StorageWrite>();

        if (status != PermissionStatus.Granted){             
            if (Permissions.ShouldShowRationale<Permissions.StorageWrite>()) { }              
            await Permissions.RequestAsync<Permissions.StorageWrite>();         
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, I am new to MAUI.Net.
In Step 1: I am getting error at HandleIntent(Intent);  
Can you please share the function of HandleIntent

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you can declare the custom webviewclient class and the custom webchromeclient class in the **\Platforms\Android** folder:

MyWebClient.cs:

```
namespace MauiApp1.Platforms.Android
{
    public class MyWebClient : WebViewClient
    {
        public override bool ShouldOverrideUrlLoading(global::Android.Webkit.WebView view, IWebResourceRequest request)
        {
            view.LoadUrl((string)request.Url);
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

MyWebChromeClient.cs:

```
namespace MauiApp1.Platforms.Android
{
    public class MyWebChromeClient : WebChromeClient
    {
        public static int filechooser = 1;
        public static IValueCallback message;


        public override bool OnShowFileChooser(global::Android.Webkit.WebView webView, IValueCallback filePathCallback, FileChooserParams fileChooserParams)
        {
            message = filePathCallback;
            Intent chooserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ActionGetContent);
            chooserIntent.AddCategory(Intent.CategoryOpenable);
            chooserIntent.SetType("*/*");
            Microsoft.Maui.ApplicationModel.Platform.CurrentActivity.StartActivityForResult(Intent.CreateChooser(chooserIntent, "File Chooser"), filechooser);
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

And then add the following code in the **\Patforms\Android\MainActivity.cs**:

```
protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, Result resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        base.OnActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if(data !=null)
        {
            if (requestCode == MyWebChromeClient.filechooser)
            {
                if(MyWebChromeClient.message !=null)
                {
                    MyWebChromeClient.message.OnReceiveValue(WebChromeClient.FileChooserParams.ParseResult((int)resultCode, data));
                    MyWebChromeClient.message = null;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Use the webview in the xaml such as:

```
<WebView x:Name="webview" HeightRequest="500"/>
```

And set the  the custom webviewclient class and the custom webchromeclient class for the webview in the page.cs:

```
protected override void OnHandlerChanged()
    {
        base.OnHandlerChanged();
#if ANDROID
        var web = webview.Handler.PlatformView as Android.Webkit.WebView;
        web.Settings.JavaScriptEnabled = true;
        web.SetWebViewClient( new Platforms.Android.MyWebClient());
        web.SetWebChromeClient(new Platforms.Android.MyWebChromeClient());
#endif
    }
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this works for me but without the need of MyWebClient.cs. Is it possible, that we don't need to add any storage or media permission at all? Because it seems to just work. One other question, what do I have to do to make it work on iOS as well?