# how to upload multiple files in webview in xamarin

Tags: android, xamarin, webview

only one file upload by this code how we upload multiple files in web view.

```
protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, [GeneratedEnum] Result resultCode, Intent data)
        {

            if (requestCode == FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE)
            {
                

                if (null == mUploadMessage) return;
                Android.Net.Uri[] result = data == null || resultCode != Result.Ok ? null : new Android.Net.Uri[] { data.Data };
                try
                {


                    Android.Content.Context context = Application.Context;
                    string text = result.Count().ToString();
                    ToastLength duration = ToastLength.Long;

                    var toast = Toast.MakeText(context, text, duration);
                    toast.Show();

                    mUploadMessage.OnReceiveValue(result);
                    

                    
                }
#pragma warning disable CS0168 // Variable is declared but never used
                catch (Exception e)
#pragma warning restore CS0168 // Variable is declared but never used
                {
                }

                mUploadMessage = null;
            }
            if (requestCode == CameraCHOOSER_RESULTCODE)
            {
                if (null == this.mUploadMessage || (resultCode != Result.Ok && !new File(filePath).Exists()))
                {
                    this.mUploadMessage.OnReceiveValue(null);
                }
                else
                {

                    Android.Net.Uri mCapturedImageURI = Android.Net.Uri.FromFile(new File(filePath.ToString()));



                    Android.Net.Uri[] results = new Android.Net.Uri[] { mCapturedImageURI };
                    mUploadMessage.OnReceiveValue(results);

                }
                this.mUploadMessage = null;
            }
            base.OnActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        }
```

I am not able to upload multiple files from webpage in webview in android xamarin. I try to search but i can not get proper solution.

Comment: There is nothing in the code you posted that tries to upload multiple files. Not even one.

Comment: You can check this answer about [Webview file upload not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76875480/net-maui-webview-file-upload-not-working).